How to prove $(x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 - x |a|^2 - y |b|^2 = - (x|a|^4 + y |b|^4)$?
Given that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$  and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$, how can one prove that
$$(x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 - x |a|^2 - y |b|^2 = - (x|a|^4 + y |b|^4)$$
I got stuck in just one step when trying to write the  $l.h.s$ as
\begin{align}
 (x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 - x |a|^2 - y |b|^2 &= - \left[ x |a|^2 + y |b|^2 - (x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 \right]\\ 
&= -\left[ (\sqrt{x} |a| + \sqrt{y} |b|)^2 - 2 \sqrt{xy} |a||b| - (x+y) |a|^2 |b|^2    \right]\\
&=???
\end{align}

There's no need to complete the square. Hint: subtract the RHS from the LHS and take out a factor of $|a|^2+|b]^2-1$. You need only check the cases $x=1,,y=0$ and $x=0,,y=1$.  Substitute $u=|a|^2,,v=|b|^2$ if that makes it easier to follow.

Use the constraint $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$:
$$(x+y)\,|a|^2 |b|^2 - x |a|^2 - y |b|^2
\;=\; (x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 - \Big(x |a|^2 +y |b|^2\Big)\Big(|a|^2 + |b|^2\Big)$$
then multiply out & simplify.

Hint: $$-x|a|^2-y|b|^2=(-x|a|^2-y|b|^2)(|a|^2+|b|^2)$$ because by assumption $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.

As an alternative, we have that wlog by a rotation
$$|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1 \iff a=\cos \theta, \;b=i\sin\theta$$
then
$$(x+y)|a|^2 |b|^2 - x |a|^2 - y |b|^2 = (x+y)\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta-x\cos^2\theta-y\sin^2\theta=$$
$$=(x+y)(1-\sin^2\theta)\sin^2\theta-x\cos^2\theta-y\sin^2\theta=$$
$$\require{cancel}=x\sin^2\theta+\cancel{y\sin^2\theta}-(x+y)\sin^4\theta-x\cos^2\theta-\cancel{y\sin^2\theta}=$$
$$=x(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)-(x+y)\sin^4\theta=$$
$$=x(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)-(x+y)\sin^4\theta=$$
$$=-(x\cos^4\theta+y\sin^4\theta)=- (x|a|^4 + y |b|^4)$$
